# Convert XHTML to XAML?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, xhtml

Good afternoon,

does anyone know of a *good* xhtml to xaml converter library / functionality? All the ones I've found are far from complete, are missing elements of the base xhtml namespace (e.g. tables etc) and what I need is to display valid xhtml in an wpf flowdocument.

Any ideas / suggestions?

Cheers & thanks
-Jörg

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to display existing XHTML, how about using a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) control?  It may require the .NET 3.5 SP1 install if you don't have it yet.  You can use the NavigateToString or NavigateToStream that [Lester shows off](http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2008/06/12/wpf-webbrowser.aspx).

```
<Grid>
    <FlowDocumentReader>
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                Hosting some XHTML.
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>
                <WebBrowser Height="100" x:Name="uiWebBrowser" />
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </FlowDocumentReader>
</Grid>
```

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    uiWebBrowser.NavigateToString("<b>Stuff</b> Stuff Stuff Stuff <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Stuff</a> Stuff <i>Stuff <h1>stuff</h1><i>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about HTML to XAML converter?

http://svn.assembla.com/svn/rsstoblog/Source/Common/HtmlToXamlConverter.cs

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972129.aspx